# IFERROR returning a null value PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to insert a formula IFERROR using PHPExcel. However, when I try to do that I'm getting a null value like there are no values at all. 
My two values that I'm getting are  **0** when I generate it will give me a #DIV/0  error. I want to change that error to a complete 0.00 only, can you help me with this?

Here's my code:

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount, 
'=IFERROR(G'.$rowCount.'/F'.$rowCount.',0)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround regarding my problem.
I've used this formula that I found in a forum from Mark Baker.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount, '=IF(F'.$rowCount.'=0, 0, G'.$rowCount.'/F'.$rowCount.')');
```